# Correct way to address messages

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Let's say I have an Android app with 100 users that I don't know personally. Is it right to make each one of them subscribe to topics like `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("<company_id>_<user_id>");` so I can address them and send notifications for one or two specifically or there is a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to send a message to specific users only, you could simply go ahead and use `to` or `registration_ids` when targeting the specific users. `registration_ids` has a limit of 1000 tokens per request.

As per the topics, it was designed to easily send messages to its subscribers. Depending on your use-case, it could be fine to subscribe them. However, you should still keep the registration tokens for each user in case you need to send specific messages.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your goal.

Anyone can subscribe to a topic, so you should only use those for sending messages targeted-but-public messages. While you can counter this a bit by making the topic names hard to guess, the inherent behavior of topics is that you lose control over precisely what devices are targeted in return for having to write less code.

If you send to a token in your own code, you determine precisely who receives the message. But you will have to run the code that maps the message to the tokens yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answers are pretty clear, I would only like to add that, this method of subscription it can be easily combined with the Firebase web console. If you want to quickly send a message to any topic, the topic is created on registration, so you only have to know the topic name.

In the Firebase Web Console, you can find the target, an application, a token for a device or a topic. If you choose a topic, just write the topic name. There is an error which always says there is no topic, disregard it, and click send, the push will be sent and the subscribers will get their notifications.